# Adding a new column in R based on maximum occurrence of words from a CSV

Tags: r, csv

I am working with two CSV files.  They are formatted like this:

```
File 1

able,2
gobble,3
highway,3
test,6
zoo,10

File 2

able,6
gobble,10
highway,3
speed,7
test,8
upper,3
zoo,10
```

In my program I want to do the following:

1. Create a keyword list by combining the values from two CSV files and keeping only unique keywords
2. Compare that keyword list to each individual CSV file to determine the maximum number of occurences of a given keyword, then append that information to the keyword list.

The first step I have done already.

I am getting confused by R reading things as vectors/factors/data frames etc...and "coercion to lists".  For example in my files given above, the maximum occurrence for the word "gobble" should be 10 (its value is 3 in file 1 and 10 in file 2)

So basically two things need to happen.  First, I need to create a column in "keywords" that holds information about the maximum number of occurrences of a word from the CSV files.  Second, I need to populate that column with the maximum value.

Here is my code:

```
# Read in individual data sets
keywordset1=as.character(read.csv("set1.csv",header=FALSE,sep=",")$V1)
keywordset2=as.character(read.csv("set2.csv",header=FALSE,sep=",")$V1)
exclude_list=as.character(read.csv("exclude.csv",header=FALSE,sep=",")$V1)

# Sort, capitalize, and keep unique values from the two keyword sets
keywords <- sapply(unique(sort(c(keywordset1, keywordset2))), toupper)

# Keep keywords greater than 2 characters in length (basically exclude in at etc...)
keywords <- keywords[nchar(keywords) > 2]

# Keep keywords that are not in the exclude list
keywords <- setdiff(keywords, sapply(exclude_list, toupper))

# HERE IS WHERE I NEED HELP

# Compare the read keyword list to the master keyword list
# and keep the frequency column

key1=read.csv("set1.csv",header=FALSE,sep=",")
key1$V1=sapply(key1[[1]], toupper)
keywords$V2=key1[which(keywords[[1]] %in% key1$V1),2]

return(keywords)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your last commmand fails is that you try to use the `$` operator on a vector. It only works on lists or data frames (which are a special case of lists).

A remark regarding `toupper` (and many other functions in R): it works on vectors, such that you don't need to use `sapply`. `toupper(c(keywordset1, keywordset2))` is perfectly fine.

But I would like to propose an entirely different solution to your problem. First, I create the data as follows:

```
keywords1 <- read.table(text="able,2
gobble,3
highway,3
test,6
zoo,10",sep=",",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

keywords2 <- read.table(text="gobble,10
highway,3
speed,7
test,8
upper,3
zoo,10",sep=",",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Note that I use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`. This prevents `read.table` from converting characters to factors, such that there is no need to call `as.character` later.

The next steps are to capitalize the keyword columns in both tables. At the same time, I put both tables in a list. This is often a good way to simplify calculations in R, because you can use `lapply` to apply a function on all the list elements. Then I put both tables into a single table.

```
keyword_list <- lapply(list(keywords1,keywords2),function(kw)
    transform(kw,V1=toupper(V1)))
keywords_all <- do.call(rbind,keyword_list)
```

The next step is to sort the data frame in decreasing order by the number in the second column:

```
keywords_sorted <- keywords_all[order(keywords_all$V2,decreasing=TRUE),]
```

`keywords_sorted` looks as follows:

```
        V1 V2
5      ZOO 10
6   GOBBLE 10
11     ZOO 10
9     TEST  8
8    SPEED  7
4     TEST  6
2   GOBBLE  3
3  HIGHWAY  3
7  HIGHWAY  3
10   UPPER  3
1     ABLE  2
```

As you notice, some keywords appear only once and for those that appear twice, the first appearance is the one  you want to keep. There is a function in R that can be used to extract exactly these elements: `duplicated()` (run `?duplicated` to learn more). Basically, the function returns `TRUE`, if an element appears for the at least second time in a vector. These are the elements you don't want. To convert `TRUE` to `FALSE` (and vice versa), you use the operator `!`. So the following gives your desired result:

```
keep <- !duplicated(keywords_sorted$V1)
keywords_max <- keywords_sorted[keep,]

        V1 V2
5      ZOO 10
6   GOBBLE 10
9     TEST  8
8    SPEED  7
3  HIGHWAY  3
10   UPPER  3
1     ABLE  2
```